# Free program to create regular expressions with a GUI

Tags: windows, regex

I am looking free program (ok if closed source) that can:

- create regular expressions with a GUI (i.e. the user don't have to deal with the regular expression syntax at al)
- work on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate

Ideally, I would like to be able in which programming language the regexp will be used, as there exist [different regular expression standards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2806693/395857) (more precisely the POSIX standard isn't always respected)

[RegexMagic](http://www.regexmagic.com/) would work except that it isn't free:

[image]

Comment: FYI [Free alternative to RegexBuddy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132405/3416774)

Comment: Thanks, that question is helpful. I have linked from it back to this

Answer (score 3):

[www.txt2re.com](http://www.txt2re.com) may be one to look into.

It seems to handle what you are looking for (create it with a web GUI, and provide it in a slew of programming languages).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Expresso Regular Expression Tool](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) has an expression builder:

[image]

and built-in libraries:

[image]

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Not a windows app, but if that isn't a barrier to you, I'd recommend [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) - it does allow you to switch between pcre/javascript/python/golang flavours, if that helps.

Comment: This is the only one of the many recommendations among the linked threads that is still updated.   A bit crammed, but does the job and even has a substitution tester also to test backreferences.